# Share models code between server and client (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller

Is there any node.js CMF to easaly share code between server and client? So I can just describe my model somehow once and then it will work by itself both on the server and on the client?

I can use Backbone of course with some hacking. But this is not the clear way.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277870/can-the-code-in-the-server-of-node-js-be-accessed-by-the-client

Comment: Is the client a web browser, or is it another type of client? If you want to use the same modules in the browser as on the server, then this may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225251/how-can-i-share-code-between-node-js-and-the-browser

Comment: My client is web browser. And so i want to have one model (smth like ActiveRecord) for both client and server. So I'll have same validations for browser and server. The only difference will be in save method (ajax request for browser and db request for server).